Implement multithreading with a queue in Delphi to limit to n threads running simultaneously?
I have been working with Delphi for some time, and am now trying to implement multi-threading in my code with the following requirements:

Only 2 threads should run at a time.

Other tasks should wait in a queue and execute once a thread becomes available.


I tried using TParallel.For to achieve this, but I couldn't implement the desired behavior. Here's my sample code:
    type
       TMyRecord = record
         msg: String;
         sleep: Integer;
          end;

    var
      Form2: TForm2;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      record1, record2, record3, record4, record5: TMyRecord;
      MyList: TList<TMyRecord>;
    begin
      // Initialize records
      record1.msg := 'Item1';
      record1.sleep := 10;

      record2.msg := 'Item2';
      record2.sleep := 10;

      record3.msg := 'Item3';
      record3.sleep := 3000;

      record4.msg := 'Item4';
      record4.sleep := 3000;

      record5.msg := 'Item5';
      record5.sleep := 100;

     MyList := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
      try
        // Add records to the list
        MyList.Add(record1);
        MyList.Add(record2);
        MyList.Add(record3);
        MyList.Add(record4);
        MyList.Add(record5);

    // Use TParallel.For
    TParallel.For(0, MyList.Count - 1,
      procedure (i: Integer)
      var
        ListItem: TMyRecord;
      begin
        ListItem := MyList[i];

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(ListItem.msg);
          end);

        Sleep(ListItem.sleep);
      end);

      finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;

I also tried using TTask.Run and ThreadPool, but was unable to achieve the desired behavior.
Updated - here is what i tried to do using Threadpool
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  record1, record2, record3, record4, record5: TMyRecord;
  MyList: TList<TMyRecord>;
  ThreadPool: TThreadPool;
begin
  // Initialize records
  record1.msg := 'Item1';
  record1.sleep := 10;

  record2.msg := 'Item2';
  record2.sleep := 10;

  record3.msg := 'Item3';
  record3.sleep := 3000;

  record4.msg := 'Item4';
  record4.sleep := 3000;

  record5.msg := 'Item5';
  record5.sleep := 100;

  MyList := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
  try
    // Add records to the list
    MyList.Add(record1);
    MyList.Add(record2);
    MyList.Add(record3);
    MyList.Add(record4);
    MyList.Add(record5);

    ThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxWorkerThreads(2);

    // Iterate through the list and queue each work item with a copy of the record
    for var i := 0 to MyList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      var ListItem := MyList[i];

      ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(
        procedure
        var
          LocalItem: TMyRecord;
        begin
          LocalItem := ListItem;

          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              Memo1.Lines.Add(LocalItem.msg);
              Sleep(LocalItem.sleep);  // Simulate the delay
            end);
        end);
    end;
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;

there is problem with this code -

it prints only 'item5' 5 times.
waiting time(sleep) is not working.

How can I modify this code to limit the number of threads running simultaneously to 2? And queue other tasks to execute as threads become available?

TParallel.For should work just fine in your example. It also supports TThreadPool. Please update your question to include the TThreadPool code you had trouble with. Did you use its SetMinWorkerThreads and SetMaxWorkerThreads methods?

yeah but what about limiting thread using TParallel.For. i have updated the question with adding threadpool code i tried, as you asked.

None of the code you have shown is using TThreadPool with TParallel.For.


it prints only 'item5' 5 times.

That implies that your queued work items are capturing the same TMyRecord, and all of your prints are happening after that variable has been assigned the last item in the list.
Even though your loop is using a local inline variable, given the way that variable capture in anonymous procedures works, it seems to be ignoring the inlining.
The common solution to having an anonymous procedure capture a variable inside a loop is to move the anonymous procedure to a separate function with an input parameter that it can capture.

waiting time(sleep) is not working.

That is likely because you are doing the sleeps in the context of the main UI thread, not in the worker threads, so they are running at full speed.
Try something more like this:
function MakeWorkItem(Item: TMyRecord): TProc;
begin
  Result := procedure
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(Item.msg);
        end
      );
      Sleep(Item.sleep);  // Simulate the delay 
    end;
end; 

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  record1, record2, record3, record4, record5: TMyRecord;
  MyList: TList<TMyRecord>;
  ThreadPool: TThreadPool;
begin
  // Initialize records
  record1.msg := 'Item1';
  record1.sleep := 10;

  record2.msg := 'Item2';
  record2.sleep := 10;

  record3.msg := 'Item3';
  record3.sleep := 3000;

  record4.msg := 'Item4';
  record4.sleep := 3000;

  record5.msg := 'Item5';
  record5.sleep := 100;

  MyList := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
  try
    // Add records to the list
    MyList.Add(record1);
    MyList.Add(record2);
    MyList.Add(record3);
    MyList.Add(record4);
    MyList.Add(record5);

    ThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxWorkerThreads(2);

    // Iterate through the list and queue each work item with a copy of the record
    for var i := 0 to MyList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(MakeWorkItem(MyList[i]));
    end;
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;

Alternatively, using TParallel.For, simply pass your desired TThreadPool to it as an extra parameter, eg:
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  record1, record2, record3, record4, record5: TMyRecord;
  MyList: TList<TMyRecord>;
  ThreadPool: TThreadPool;
begin
  // Initialize records
  record1.msg := 'Item1';
  record1.sleep := 10;

  record2.msg := 'Item2';
  record2.sleep := 10;

  record3.msg := 'Item3';
  record3.sleep := 3000;

  record4.msg := 'Item4';
  record4.sleep := 3000;

  record5.msg := 'Item5';
  record5.sleep := 100;

  MyList := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
  try
    // Add records to the list
    MyList.Add(record1);
    MyList.Add(record2);
    MyList.Add(record3);
    MyList.Add(record4);
    MyList.Add(record5);

    ThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxWorkerThreads(2);

    // Use TParallel.For
    TParallel.For(0, MyList.Count - 1,
      procedure (i: Integer)
      var
        ListItem: TMyRecord;
      begin
        ListItem := MyList[i];

        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(ListItem.msg);
          end
        );

        Sleep(ListItem.sleep);
      end,
      TThreadPool // <-- HERE
    );
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;


Oh, that was much clearer. I understand both ways clearly now. Thank you!

You can fairly easily use a TThreadedQueue for this which is designed for this task.
I put together a little demo:
https://github.com/ideasawakened/DelphiKB/tree/master/Delphi%20Demos/TThreadedQueue/TwoClientThreads_MainThreadProducer

Create a TThreadedQueue
Spin off 2 Client Worker Threads
Produce TMyRecords with a click of a button and use PushItem to add them to the Queue and the 2 worker threads will complete them in order.

Example code.  (+ add a TButton/TMemo to a form...)
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type

  TMyRecord = record
    id:Integer;
    msg:string;
    sleep:Integer;
  end;

  TMyRecConsumerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fQueue:TThreadedQueue<TMyRecord>;
    fThreadNumber:Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(const Queue:TThreadedQueue<TMyRecord>; const ThreadNumber:Integer);

    procedure Execute(); override;
  end;


  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Memo1:TMemo;
    butProduce:TButton;
    procedure butProduceClick(Sender:TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender:TObject);
  private const
    ConsumerThreadCount = 2;

    QueueDepth = 100;
    ProduceCount = 5;
    PushTimeout = 500;
    PopTimeout = 3000;
  private
    fQueue:TThreadedQueue<TMyRecord>;
    fRecId:Integer;
    fConsumers:TArray<TMyRecConsumerThread>;
    function CreateWorkItem:TMyRecord;
  end;

var
  MainForm:TMainForm;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.SyncObjs;

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  fRecId := 1;
  butProduce.Caption := Format('Produce %d records', [ProduceCount]);

  fQueue := TThreadedQueue<TMyRecord>.Create(QueueDepth, PushTimeout, PopTimeout);

  SetLength(fConsumers, ConsumerThreadCount);
  for var i := 1 to ConsumerThreadCount do
  begin
    fConsumers[i-1] := TMyRecConsumerThread.Create(fQueue, i);
  end;
end;


procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender:TObject);
begin
  for var ConsumerThread in fConsumers do
  begin
    ConsumerThread.Free;
  end;
  fQueue.DoShutDown;
  fQueue.Free;
end;


function TMainForm.CreateWorkItem:TMyRecord;
begin
  Result := Default(TMyRecord);
  Result.id := fRecId;
  Result.sleep := Random(PopTimeout div 2);
  Result.msg := Format('Task %d sleeping %dms', [fRecId, Result.sleep]);

  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Produced Task %d to sleep %dms', [fRecId, Result.sleep]));
  Inc(fRecId);
end;


//click the button one or more times to queue up some work items
procedure TMainForm.butProduceClick(Sender:TObject);
var
  wr:TWaitResult;
begin
  for var i := 1 to ProduceCount do
  begin
    wr := fQueue.PushItem(CreateWorkItem);
    Assert(wr = TWaitResult.wrSignaled);  // IRL deal with <> wrSignaled (e.g., timeout if queue is full)
  end;
end;


constructor TMyRecConsumerThread.Create(const Queue:TThreadedQueue<TMyRecord>; const ThreadNumber:Integer);
begin
  fQueue := Queue;
  fThreadNumber := ThreadNumber;
  inherited Create({CreateSuspended=}False);
end;


procedure TMyRecConsumerThread.Execute;
var
  wr:TWaitResult;
  r:TMyRecord;
begin
  NameThreadForDebugging(Format('Consumer%d', [fThreadNumber]));

  while (not Terminated) and (not fQueue.ShutDown) do
  begin
    wr := fQueue.PopItem(r);
    if (wr = wrSignaled) then
    begin
      if r.id > 0 then //Note: if 0, then PopItem was signalled as Queue was told to shut down (rec will be "Default(TMyRecord)")
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            MainForm.Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Consumed %s', [r.msg]));
          end);
        sleep(r.sleep); //would be better to have an abortable sleep using an TEvent
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


end.


This is a great approach and offers a different perspective. It might suit my problem better. Thank you for sharing!
